# Xorg fail to use my graphic card

Tags: drivers, radeon, fglrx

Xorg use the Intel GMA but I want to use my ATI Radeon card.

Here from Xorg logs :

> (II) LoadModule: "fglrx"
>
> (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fglrx
>
> (II) UnloadModule: "fglrx"
>
> (II) Unloading fglrx
>
> (EE) Failed to load module "fglrx" (module does not exist, 0)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Ubuntu 12.10 right?

If that is so, 12.10 does not have support right now for the legacy fglrx driver. If you want to install them anyway, you can follow this guide:

http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/10/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-legacy.html

Comment: Doesn't work, each time I try to use the proprietary driver GNOME go into the fallback mod. I've this problem with all Ubuntu dist.